# If you are asked to draw a point, A, due south to another point, B, does this mean you draw a vertical line from point B to A?

Tags: trigonometry

> If you are asked to draw a point, A, due south to another point, B, does this mean you draw a vertical line from point B to A?

If not, can someone help me draw this line?

Comment: yes, and of course downward from B to A